# re: behaviour of a UserControl in a designer and at runtime

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to create a `StackPanel` user control that would allow me to stack newly added controls in a vertical fashion (like a WPF StackPanel but using Windows forms).

I created a new user control with the core code shown below, but even though my Location gets asigned right values in designer I can pop message boxes, the designer view does not re-arange the child controls that I drag and drop onto my stack panel, also at runtime my location seems to be overwriten with what the designer thinks is right (a Location of where I placed the control)

```
Public Class StackPanel
    Inherits Panel
    Private biasHeight As Integer = 0
    Private Sub StackPanel_ControlAdded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ControlEventArgs) Handles MyBase.ControlAdded
        Dim newControl As System.Windows.Forms.Control = e.Control
        '
        ' NOT WORKING: Set location of the newly added control in a panel and at runtime
        '
        newControl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, biasHeight)
        '
        ' Store the y-cooridnate of the next control
        '
        biasHeight = biasHeight + newControl.Height
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Use `FlowLayoutPanel` instead.

Comment: Thank you, yes that is definitively the right way. Although I still would like to understand why my UserControl is not working as I would hope it would. The above example is just a simplification of a control I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically these kind of things will be done by implementing the custom [LayoutEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.layout.layoutengine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Msdn has a sample as well.

Am not sure why your code doesn't work, no reason to go behind it because it is terribly flawed. You are just setting the Location only when adding new control. There are lot more. You need to consider when a control is removed, when some control is hidden(visible set to false), When Size changed, When Padding changed etc etc.

So, Instead of reinventing the wheel I suggest you to use `FlowLayoutPanel`. If at all you want to implement it yourself then do it right. I mean create your `LayoutEngine` as shown in the provided link. In fact that link do have what you need.